# MMlogic, traffic light

Tags: c++

I'm using this program called MMlogic. I want to simulate a traffic light.

```
Counter = 1 = red light
Counter = 2 = green light
Counter = 3 = yellow light
```

The counter is giving binary signals. So 1 = 1, 2 = 01, 3 = 11.

How do i make the correct light show up? I have output 1 attached to the red light and two to the green light, but when it goes to 3 (11 in binary), it lights all the lights (I have 1 & 2 attached to an AND port).

So what I want is that only the yellow light works.

Do you have a solution? See this screenshot: http://www.uploadplaatjes.nl/plaatje.php?id=432369

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create truth tables for each of your outputs. 
For light 3, AND is good, for lights 1 and 2, a (NOT A) AND B and its symmetrical should work. 
(I call A, B the two bits).

Comment: Thanks, using that method I got a lot further!

Comment: @Andre: if my answer was helpful, I would appreciate it if you could give it an arrow up (mark it as useful), thank you.